# Which topics do I need to subscribe to in order to get the next job in AWS IoT?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I'm hoping to clarify what topics I need to subscribe to in order to get the next job off the queue in AWS IoT.

Based on [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/jobs-devices.html) it looks like I should just need to subscribe to the `notify-next` topic. However, when I do that I don't actually get the next job when my application starts up, even if I issue the describe request for the job `$next`. That information comes in on the `jobs/$next/get/accepted` topic. Do I need to subscribe to that topic too? I'm worried about getting duplicate jobs if I subscribe to both.

Here is some python code using the [AWSIoTMQTTThingJobsClient](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python) that does **not** work. This will only notify me if the next job changes, I don't get the original next job when starting up.

```
client.createJobSubscription(
    callback=handle_job,
    jobExecutionType=jobExecutionTopicType.JOB_NOTIFY_NEXT_TOPIC)
client.sendJobsDescribe('$next')
```

Ideally my application does the following:

- On startup, get the next job in the queue and execute it
- After executing a job, see if there is another job on the queue, if so, execute that next
- If new jobs are created while the application is running, asynchronously get the job details and execute it (i.e., don't poll for new jobs)

I am able to make this happen by changing the code above to this

```
client.createJobSubscription(
    callback=handle_job,
    jobExecutionType=jobExecutionTopicType.JOB_DESCRIBE_TOPIC,
    jobReplyType=jobExecutionTopicReplyType.JOB_ACCEPTED_REPLY_TYPE,
    jobId='$next')
client.createJobSubscription(
    callback=handle_job,
    jobExecutionType=jobExecutionTopicType.JOB_NOTIFY_NEXT_TOPIC)
client.sendJobsDescribe('$next')
```

Basically, add in another subscriber to `jobs/$next/get/accepted` so the first job can be fetched. But for the rest of the duration of the application just use the `notify-next` topic. It's just that most sample code or documentation indicates that I shouldn't need that extra subscription, so I want to make sure I'm not doing anything wrong.